# What's label currying in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

In Prometheus, there's label currying. Some example methods are like `CurryWith()`.

What's the meaning of it? Sorry I didn't find any documentation for this.

Problem might be related to that English is not my native language, and I don't understand `curry` from the function name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In mathematics and computer science, currying is the technique of converting a function that takes multiple arguments into a sequence of functions that each takes a single argument.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to fill in some but not all label value.
You can check it here: https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/prometheus/gauge.go#L246